# matplotlib data dependent plotting speed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to speed up my matplotlib plots for ~100K (ideally ~5M) points of sampled square waves and hit a performance issue I can't easily explain.

Here's a simple test code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

arr1 = np.tile(np.array([0, .01, .02, .01, .02, .01, .03, .05, .07, 1, .9, .8, .9]), 10000) # 3 sec
arr2 = np.tile(np.array([0, .01, .02, .01, .02, .01, .03, .05, .07, 1, .9, .8, 1]), 10000)  # 1 sec

for data in [arr1, arr2, arr1, arr2]:
    fig = plt.figure()
    start = time.clock()
    plt.plot(data)
    plt.show(False)

    print "Elapsed %.1f" % (time.clock() - start)

    plt.close()
```

Plotting `arr1` took 3 seconds, `arr2` is only 1 second.
The only difference is in the last (repeated) element, 0.9 vs. 1, but it should not change the vertical scaling and thus I can't explain the 3x speed difference between these plots. I'm using python 2.7/matplotlib 1.5.1.

Can someone tell me what is the reason for the huge performance drop in the first case?

Comment: not really sure but it could be the additional time needed to load the library. try plotting using different programs and check if the time difference is consistant

Comment: I plot both arrays twice, plotting times are  3 sec, 1 sec, 3 sec, 1 sec.

Comment: Not sure what the actual cause of it is but seems to be a Python 2.7 problem. I tried with Anaconda, and Python 3.4 and both do not reproduce the issue but Python 2.7 does...